# error in generating pdf using iTextSharp means previous pdf file is diplayed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, itext

I am working in asp .net mvc3.

I have these statements in controller class:

```
PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream((Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\Receipt5.pdf"),
FileMode.Create));
doc.Open();
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);

table.AddCell("tt[0]");
table.AddCell("tt[1]");
doc.close();
```

All time my values are changing but in pdf sometimes showing old result. please tell me what should i do for it that whenever i press done button then new pdf document should generate.

i am using iTextSharp to generate pdf.

Comment: Also, see my response to your other question about completely avoiding writing to the file system in the first place. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519169/error-in-generating-pdf-using-itextsharp/6521402#6521402

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're not able to replace the old file cause it is locked.
Try to delete it and see what happens.
Anyway, consider that if more than one user tries to print the same document you can have a concurrency problem.
I would suggest you to use a generated file name:

```
var newFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".pdf");
```

Comment: Sir you may right,but please suggest what should i write to view new generated pdf ? means what should i write in place of  Response.Redirect("~/Receipt5.pdf");   means how can i see my new generated file.

Comment: @Pushpendra Kuntal: I normally do what Chris Haas has suggested: memory stream.